# How would you explain this math equation in simple words?

Tags: linear-algebra

[math equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89jR8.png)

$$
c(x,y,f(x)) = (1 - y*f(x))_+ = \begin{cases}
0, & y * f(x) \geq 1\\
1 - y*f(x), & \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$

Hi guys. Pardon if this is a silly question I'm still new to a number of mathematical interpretations and I saw this formula whiles reading an article on the internet. I wanted to know how I would explain the underlined bit in "human words". I know f(x) means function of x. Can't seem to put everything together.

Thank you so much

Comment: Given a function $F$, the function $F_+$ is the "[positive part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts)" of the function and outputs the same as the original function in the event the output was non-negative and outputs zero instead otherwise.  Note that every function can be written as the sum of its positive and negative parts.

Comment: Here, the author is commenting on the fact that the function $c$ is itself the positive part of the function $(1-y\ast f(x))$

Comment: To add to the previous comments: the condition $y*f(x)\ge 1$ is exactly equivalent to the condition $1 - y*f(x) \le 0$.